# "Sockpuppet" en castellano

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, jerga-internet

Estaba leyendo la noticia [Wikipedia expulsa a cientos de editores por cobrar a empresas](http://tecnologia.elpais.com/tecnologia/2015/09/04/actualidad/1441375167_988480.html) cuando me encontré con el fragmento:

> (...) Es habitual que los editores detecten y eliminen artículos que
>   incumplen las normas de la enciclopedia y que sirven para dar
>   relevancia a entidades y personas que —en comparación con la mayoría
>   de los demás textos— no las merecen, pero resulta extraordinario que
>   el portal dé la orden de un despido masivo de **perfiles** por
>   considerarlos **títeres de calcetín o sockpuppets** (cuentas creadas
>   específicamente para publicar artículos saltándose las normas)

Y me pregunto: ¿cuán frecuente es el término "sockpuppet" en castellano y cuán reconocido es su traducción literal "títere de calcetín"? ¿Existe alguna preferencia al respecto o alguna traducción alternativa?

Además: ¿llamamos "títere de calcetín" a la imagen siguiente? Es decir, no al término usado en internet, sino al calcetín usado como jugueto. En castellano nunca oí tal palabra, si bien es cierto que tampoco vi muchos.

[image]

Comment: La verdad es que me llama mucho la atención esa traducción que referencias en la pregunta. En determinados contextos yo traduciría _sockpuppets_ simplemente como "cuenta falsa" y dejaría aparte la referencia a los calcetines. No sé el porqué de forzar la traducción de esa manera, cuando queda mucho menos claro y es casi indispensable la explicación entre paréntesis...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La segunda acepción que nos da el DRAE para la palabra [*títere*](http://dle.rae.es/t%C3%ADtere) es *persona que se deja manejar por otra*. Aunque el DRAE no da más explicaciones en este sentido, en la práctica extendemos este significado a otros entes distintos de las personas, yuxtaponiendo la palabra. Así, un *gobierno títere* es aquel que actúa en un país bajo las órdenes de una potencia extranjera. Por tanto, en mi opinión, la expresión correcta en español para el concepto que maneja Wikipedia es *cuenta títere*.

En cuanto al significado principal de la palabra *sockpuppet*, no conozco ninguna palabra específica en castellano. Creo haber leído la traducción literal *títere de calcetín* en algún libro de manualidades.

Comment: +1. Yo habría sugerido [**marioneta**](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=marioneta), pero es básicamente sinónimo de _títere_. Hace tiempo estuve pensando en esta cuestión yo también y no encontré término en español que recoja el matiz de "calcetín" para referirse a esta clase de marioneta.

Comment: ¡Gracias por la respuesta! Curiosamente encontré una web que habla de los ["calcetines marioneta"](http://www.guiainfantil.com/articulos/ocio/manualidades/calcetin-marioneta-manualidad-de-reciclaje-para-ninos/), lo que incide en lo sugerido por @Diego en cuanto a que marioneta y títere son palabras bastante sinónimas (si es que ser sinónimo es cuantificable :D). En general, voe que se usa con más frecuencia "títere de calcetín".

Comment: Me gusta la idea de traducir el concepto en vez de calcar.  La jerga informática en inglés ya tiene demasiadas palabras opacas —pero que suena muy *guais*— que nadie entiende con facilidad y por ende casi siempre requieren traducción laica entre parentesis o frases para enlazar el concepto con el término.  No hay que repetir esa costumbre (errónea, opino) en castellano.

Comment: En Wikipedia hay un articulo al respecto, [Usuarios titeres](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Usuarios_t%C3%ADteres). Y de títeres [hay varios tipos](http://www.teiamoner.com/llicencia/tipusE.htm). Un caso similar sería el de un negro, incluido en la RAE  (o escritor fantasma) que escribe por otro escritor, en inglés ghostwriter.

Comment: Gracias por el enlace, @AlexBcn. No sabía que existía ese artículo.

Answer (score 4):

En la entrada sobre [Shari Lewis en Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shari_Lewis) se refiere a Lambchop como un "muñeco".  No sé si este uso es común.

[image]
Lamb Chop (puppet)

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer and adding a picture of the Lambchop puppet (showing the arm, so it is clear what kind of puppet it is). Some of us are not that familiar with this cultural reference, so I thought this would help illustrating. Also, even for famous puppets as Kermit the Frog, names could be translated (_La rana Gustavo_ en español...) making the reference less clear so I thought this would help clarifying.

Comment: In Mexico, Kermit the Frog was named "La rana René".

Comment: Good Edit.   I'm hoping some other answer will deal with the internet slang usage (widely used in Stack Exchange meta).  And that has to be a humorous back reference to the Sesame street gang, probably more widely known than Lambchop, although Lambchop is older.

Comment: It's interesting that, in international politics, when a supposed ruler of one country was really completely under the control of some foreign ruler, the phrase used (in English) was a "puppet" ruler.  So the imagery predates the internet and Sesame Street by more than a century.  Did Napoleon put a puppet ruler on the Spanish throne?  What Spanish phrase is used for that situation?

Answer (score 1):

En Argentina, los llamamos [Títeres de mano](http://www.planetamama.com.ar/nota/t%C3%ADteres-de-mano) y se pueden construir con bolsas de papel, con medias.

Segun cita [planetamama,](http://www.planetamama.com.ar/nota/caracter%C3%ADsticas-del-beb%C3%A9-6-meses) en su nota *Características del bebé de 6 meses*:

> Con una esponja- títere, algún títere de colores contrastantes o simplemente con una media de algodón blanca y nueva en la que podamos dibujar una carita con marcador indeleble, es posible entretenerlo.

Comment: ¡Qué bien! Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Bienvenida a [spanish.se], por cierto :)